# Cross section of the river

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, hec-georas

I am working in ArcGIS 10.5 and HEC-GeoRAS. I want to make cross section of a river, with cross section intervals of 100 metres.

As there is option in hec-geo Ras to make the cross section with intervals but interval unit is in decimal degrees.

How I can make the cross sections in metres?

Answer (score 1):

Most tools in ArcGIS honour the coordinate system of the input data. If your data is in decimal degrees, then your intervals will be in decimal degrees. Try converting your data to a projected coordinate system with units in either feet or metres.

You can use the **[Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm)** tool to get your data into an appropriate coordinate system.

I'm not familiar with HEC-GeoRAS, but if you're doing analysis on a DEM or DTM, it makes sense that you'll need to convert your data to a projected coordinate system instead of a geographic coordinate system.